# How to set which storage account is used for web jobs (via Portal)

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-webjobs, azureportal

Where in the portal (classic or new) can you define which storage account to use for web jobs?

In particular, the AzureWebJobsDashboard and AzureWebJobsStorage connection strings.  In my app.config, I have these set, but I want to use a different storage account for each environment (as I am using TimerTriggers which require a singleton lock on these).

After creating the storage accounts, is there a clean way to associate the hosting web app (or individual web job) with the appropriate storage account connection string via the Portal?

Kind regards,

Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it in the classic portal under the web app for your web job under **Application Diagnostics**
[image]

[image]

Or in the new portal under your web app under **Diagnostics Logs**
[image]

Comment: Thanks Tom.  Do you know if I can also just create connection strings in the Azure Portal (application settings) with AzureWebJobsDashboard and AzureWebJobsStorage and set the values appropriately there also?

Comment: I looked at the source code and it looks like it tries to take a singleton lock on the blob storage ...

Comment: IStorageBlobDirectory lockDirectory = GetLockDirectory(attribute.Account); 
IStorageBlockBlob lockBlob = lockDirectory.GetBlockBlobReference(lockId); 
TimeSpan lockPeriod = GetLockPeriod(attribute, _config); 
string leaseId = await TryAcquireLeaseAsync(lockBlob, lockPeriod, cancellationToken);

Comment: But thanks Tom, I'll mark yours as answer as I think I can try and edit the blob storage account for my purpose of timer triggers

Comment: These settings only affect the diagnostic logging and not the webjobs SDK.

Answer (score 4):

The AzureWebJobsDashboard and AzureWebJobsStorage connection strings can be found in the preview portal (https://portal.azure.com) under App Services -> [Your app that hosts the webjobs] -> Application Settings.  There is a group of Connection Strings that you can edit[image]

Comment: This is the correct answer. If you have values defined in your config, you can also override those here.